# Scroll view not scrolling back down when keyboard closes

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have used apples guide on Moving content located under the keyboard

[Guide here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

It works very well in scrolling up when the keyboard opens but when the keyboard is closed it doesn't scroll back down and I am left with the top of the scroll view cut off.

my Code

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
 - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    _myScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _myScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    } 
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _myScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _myScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to tell [self.myScrollView setContentOffset:CGSizeMake(0,0) animated:YES]; in your keyboardWillBeHidden method?

Comment: @Zhang I don't know see this is where I am stuck I'm just getting this off the apple site.

Comment: OK....did your keyboardWillBeHidden get executed?

Comment: @Zhang Yep, defiantly gets executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I use when the keyboard resigns.  I had trouble with your original code because it seems not to want to work in iOS 7.

```
-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
    // Get the keyboard size
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

    //add keyboard size to current scrollview frame
    frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.height;

    //apply frame to scrollview
    self.scrollView.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working Swift 2.0 code translation for **urnotsam**'s Objective C code:

```
func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions
    let info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
    var scrollViewFrame: CGRect = self.scrollView.frame

    // Begin animation
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)

    scrollViewFrame.size.height += (keyboardSize?.height)!
    // Apply it
    self.scrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame
    // Now animate
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```